# Highcharts: Bar with negative stack - Place title text at each side

Tags: highcharts

I'm wondering if it is possible to place two text titles at each side (negative/positive), centralized on each side.

I tried with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-negative-stack/).

```
   ...
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: "right",
                align: "right"
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },
        {
            title: {
                text: "left",
                align: "left"
            }              
        }
```

I tried to add another yxis, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you try to achieve? Maybe you have a picture of the desired result? You can always use renderer to render the text/label wherever you want http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label

Comment: Yes!
Take a look on this https://jsfiddle.net/gravatasufoca/5htbkwts/

Answer (score 0):

you can only set xaxis title  to

> "low", "middle" by default, "high"

but for multiple title ,i think its not possible via api, it depends on your axis.
like you have one xaxis and 2 yaxis, 
so you can have title separatly on both yaxis but not on xaxis.

the problem is you cant get the center point (0,0), if you can get **Y** of this point then you can update **Y** for the title.

Comment: So I need to discover the and from both, and set them manually.
Actually, I need to change x, and, because now they are one underneath the other